# optimal way to index a xref table

Tags: sql, database, performance, postgresql, database-design

Image a table foobar that stores certain information pertaining to unique {foo, bar} pairs.  It has these columns:

id pkey
foo_id foreign key to foo(id)
bar_id foreign key to bar(id)
baz

The table needs to be queried by foo_id alone, bar_id alone, and by both together.  Two ways I see to index the table are:

1. Unique index on (foo_id, bar_id) plus a non-unique index on (bar_id).

or

2. Unique index on (bar_id, foo_id) plus a non-unique index on (foo_id).

What characteristics of the data in "foobar" would make one of those preferable to the other?

For the sake of argument, assume that the table "foobar" contains approximately 10x as many unique foo_id values as it does unique bar_id values.

EDITED TO ADD:

If it helps, the actual table is an xref between "mobile users" and "mobile devices".  The # of unique "mobile device" values is approximately 95% the number of rows in the xref table.  The # of unique "mobile users" is approximately 35% the number of rows in the xref table.

Comment: You're interested in selectivity and in the frequency of individual column accesses. You'll want the most-selective column (i.e. the column with the greatest number of unique values / number of total values) first in a composite index where possible.

Comment: Hmm.  I'm not sure I see why it would matter, since I'm going to add the second (non-unique) on the column that isn't first in the compound index.  In my example, with option #1, a query against foo_id would use the compound index.  A query on bar_id would use the single-column index on bar_id.  I'll going to update my question with what "foo" and "bar" really represent; perhaps it will add clarity.

Comment: I created some indexes and looked at the sizes.  The compound index was the same size (on postgres) regardless of column order. However, a single-column index on the less-specific column was smaller than a single-column index on the more specific column.  This suggests that, in my example, I should make the compound index on (foo_id, bar_id) and then create a second single-column index on (bar_id).  That sound right?

Comment: Was wrong about the sizes.  The one that looked bigger was only bigger because it had already existed for a while.  I re-indexed it and then both were the same size.